# How to write some code to tell if a variable is signed or not

Tags: c, macros, unsigned, signed

I want to write a function (or macro) that tells whether or not a variable is signed. That is, how to tell if the given variable's **type** is signed or not, as opposed to its **value**.

Comment: You can't. C doesn't provide any way to introspect variable types.

Comment: What would be the usecase of such a function/macro? You always *know* the type of your variables when you write them in your code. The only unknown signedness is of the type `char`, but you can check it with `limits.h` definitions

Comment: It's the other way around: it is the type that tells C whether you intend it to be signed.

Comment: @Barmar: C provides `_Generic` to introspect types.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Re “You always know the type of your variables when you write them in your code”: A person does not always write all the code in their program, nor does a person always write a program for their code. For example, sometimes features are provided via header files that can plug into various code, and one might want to adapt some feature so it can work with one type or another that is defined by the user of the header file rather than by the header file’s author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `_Generic` macro:

```
#define is_signed(X) _Generic((X), \
                short : true, \
                int : true, \
                long : true, \
                long long : true, \
                unsigned short : false, \
                unsigned int : false, \
                unsigned long : false, \
                unsigned long long : false, \
                float : true, \
                double : true, \
                long double : true \
               )
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xdEETYjan)

---

You could also delegate to functions if you'd like to do something more complicated. I've made a simple example where `is_signed` returns a `signs` object including the signedness of both the `type` and the `value` of the supplied variable. I've excluded the parameter names where they are not needed, which will be allowed in the C2x standard. You can add dummy names if you want.

```
typedef struct { bool type; bool value; } signs;

signs Short(short x) { signs r={true, x < 0}; return r; }
signs Int(int x) { signs r={true, x < 0}; return r; }
signs Long(long x) { signs r={true, x < 0}; return r; }
signs Longlong(long long x) { signs r={true, x < 0}; return r; }

signs UShort(unsigned short) { signs r={false, false}; return r; }
signs UInt(unsigned int) { signs r={false, false}; return r; }
signs ULong(unsigned long) { signs r={false, false}; return r; }
signs ULonglong(unsigned long long) { signs r={false, false}; return r; }

signs Float(float x) { signs r={true, x < 0.f}; return r; }
signs Double(double x) { signs r={true, x < 0.}; return r; }
signs LongDouble(long double x) { signs r={true, x < 0.L}; return r; }

#define is_signed(X) _Generic((X), \
                short : Short, \
                int : Int, \
                long : Long, \
                long long : Longlong, \
                unsigned short : UShort, \
                unsigned int : UInt, \
                unsigned long : ULong, \
                unsigned long long : ULonglong, \
                float : Float, \
                double : Double, \
                long double : LongDouble \
               )(X)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jMeva9xa9)

Comment: Is there any advantage in having the function calls?

Comment: I was thinking you could just have `short: true,`  `unsigned short: false,` etc., also `char: CHAR_MIN < 0,` (see Eric's answer). Depends if you want the argument of `is_signed(x)` to be evaluated or not.

Comment: @IanAbbott I got that working. Thanks for questioning it! :-)

Comment: It's going to be tricky to maintain a list of all the different integer types like this.  There are compilers out there that support unusual integer types like 24-bit integers (XC8 for PICs) and 128-bit integers (GCC for x86_64).

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes, for non-standard types one would have to make special lookup tables. One could start with this one and if  it fails, one would have to build a new table supporting the platform specific set of types one has to deal with in that case. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/c4KvcfMsr)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for explicitly listed types using `_Generic`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum Signedness { Signed, Unsigned, Unknown };
    char x;
    enum Signedness s = _Generic(x,
            char:               CHAR_MIN < 0 ? Signed : Unsigned,
            signed char:        Signed,
            unsigned char:      Unsigned,
            short:              Signed,
            unsigned short:     Unsigned,
            int:                Signed,
            unsigned:           Unsigned,
            long:               Signed,
            unsigned long:      Unsigned,
            long long:          Signed,
            unsigned long long: Unsigned,
            default:            Unknown
            );
    switch (s)
    {
        case Signed:
            printf("The type is signed.\n");
            break;
        case Unsigned:
            printf("The type is unsigned.\n");
            break;
        case Unknown:
            printf("It is not known whether the type is signed or unsigned.\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an imperfect way of doing it:

```
#define isSigned(x) ((x) < 0 ? 1 : (-(x) < 0 ? 1 : 0))
```

If the number compares less than 0, its type is obviously signed.  Otherwise, it's positive, but if its negation is less than 0, again, it was signed.

But, whoops, it's not that simple, because it's also possible the value is 0!  (Thanks, @JohnBollinger.)  If it's exactly 0, then if `x-1` is negative, it was signed.

```
#define isSigned(x) ((x) < 0 ? 1 : (x) > 0 ? (-(x) < 0 ? 1 : 0) : ((x) - 1 < 0 ? 1 : 0))
```

(Unfortunately, the extra clause to handle the `x == 0` case tips it over the edge from "barely readable" to "just about completely obfuscated.)

In any case, this assumes the variable does have a value (that is, has been initialized).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all for types smaller than `int`, because in that case, `-x` is negative even if `x` was unsigned.

Demonstration:

```
int main()
{
    char c = 1;
    unsigned char uc = 1;
    signed char sc = 1;
    int i = -1;
    unsigned u = 1;
    float f = 1;
    double d = -1;

    printf("char: %ssigned\n",          isSigned(c) ? "" : "un");
    printf("signed char: %ssigned\n",   isSigned(sc) ? "" : "un");
    printf("unsigned char: %ssigned\n", isSigned(uc) ? "" : "un");
    printf("int: %ssigned\n",           isSigned(i) ? "" : "un");
    printf("unsigned: %ssigned\n",      isSigned(u) ? "" : "un");
    printf("float: %ssigned\n",         isSigned(f) ? "" : "un");
    printf("double: %ssigned\n",        isSigned(d) ? "" : "un");
}
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but it gives the wrong answer when the argument has a signed type and value zero.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Whoops! Dang. I shoulda thoughta that. Fixed (at the cost of some extra obfuscation).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I present two solutions that work  on all integer types, and do not require you to come up with a list of all possible intger types.

## Solution using C extensions

This works fine in GCC.  It uses the [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) extension.

```
#define SIGNFIND(x) ((typeof(x))-1 < 1)
```

## Plain C solution

This works without using C extensions.  However, it seems dangerous since it modifies one of the bytes of your variable (temporarily). Also, it assumes your system uses little endian byte order, but that would be pretty easy to fix (just expand it to set all bits of the variable to 1).  Also, if the variable has not been initialized when you run this, you are probably invoking undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

uint8_t * signfind_ptr;
uint8_t signfind_save;

bool signfind_start(uint8_t * v)
{
  signfind_ptr = v;
  signfind_save = *signfind_ptr;
  *signfind_ptr = 0xFF;
  return false;
}

bool signfind_end(bool s)
{
  *signfind_ptr = signfind_save;
  return s;
}

#define SIGNFIND(x) (signfind_start((uint8_t *)&(x) + sizeof(x) - 1), signfind_end((x) < 1))

int main()
{
  char v_char = 0;
  unsigned char v_uchar = 0;
  int v_int = 0;
  uint64_t v_u64 = 0;

  printf("char: %d\n", SIGNFIND(v_char));
  printf("unsigned char: %d\n", SIGNFIND(v_uchar));
  printf("int: %d\n", SIGNFIND(v_int));
  printf("uint64_t: %d\n", SIGNFIND(v_u64));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is only possible with a macro because function's arguments have a pre-defined type.

If you are passing a variable: `#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a >= 0 && ~a >=0)`

If you are passing a type: `#define ISUNSIGNED(type) ((type)0 - 1 > 0)`

For the first: The essential characteristic of an unsigned value is that is cannot be negative. The characteristic of a signed variable is that complementing it most significant bit will change the sign (under 2's complement). Because the other bits are irrelevant, just change them all using `~`. (It works. Just get a sample number, negative or not, and work it out on a notepad.)

The second just uses type casts.